# How to sort Scala maps by value in ascending order?

Tags: scala, sorting, dictionary, key-value

I have a map like so:

```
var map:Map[String, Double] = Map(
 "1" -> 4.6, 
 "2" -> 2.1, 
 "3" -> 3.4, 
 "4" -> 0.3
)
```

I would like to sort it by values in the ascending order so as to get the following output after printing each key value pair in the map:

```
(4,0.3)
(2,2.1)
(3,3.4)
(1,4.6)
```

How can I do this? Obviously the sorted method doesn't exist so I'd have to convert the Map to another data type and work from there.

Answer (score 4):

Just transform the Map to a List and apply `sortBy` with an orderer for Double (for `Scala 2.13`+), like below:

```
implicit val orderer = Ordering.Double.TotalOrdering

myMap.toList.sortBy(_._2)
// res1: List[(String, Double)] = List((4,0.3), (2,2.1), (3,3.4), (1,4.6))
```

Comment: What does (_._2) mean?

Comment: It's a short form for `x => x._2` to indicate that you want to sort the list of Tuple2's by the 2nd element of each Tuple.